# Size of somatosensory overlap/intermediate zone for pain/light touch

Tags: neurology, pain, tactile-touch

For somatosensory innervation, there is a substantial overlap within the spinal cord and dermatomes, so that the (maximal) innervation zones of adjacent spinal roots form overlapping/intermediate zones (Fig. below). Anecdotal wisdom tells that the overlap is less for pain compared to light touch. However, I simply cannot find source publications in Pubmed and Google regarding the extent of overlap for different sensory modalities, using keywords like "autonomous zone", "overlap" etc. Can someone help out with references (original publications, or at least accepted textbook screenshots/images)?

Fig. source: https://clinicalgate.com/the-somatosensory-system-ii-nociception-thermal-sense-and-touch/

[image]